# Record Controls inside jquery ui is not saving

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

Say I have this html/asp tag:

```
<div id="details2" style="display:none;width=1000px;">
<GEN:RECORD NAME="SampleRecordControl" /> 
<GEN:Button Name="SaveButton" />
</div>
```

SampleRecordControl is my repeater which contains my textboxes that is connected to the database but when i click the save button i got null values.. I am using Jquery UI. can anyone tell me what i need to do about this?

this is my jquery code:

```
$("#details2").dialog2({
        title: "Create Title",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $(this).dialog2('close');


            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
```

this is just the only problem i have so i can save my data on database hope you help can help me solve this

Comment: Not [tag:asp-classic].

Comment: i don't know the difference sir i am just newbie here..

Comment: http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/AspNet-Tutorial-26.aspx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered.. thanks to this code snippet

```
          open: function(type,data) {
$(this).parent().appendTo("form");}
```